# Ubuntu 14.04 Installation Failure on 2012 MBP - Missing Operating System

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, macbook-pro

everyone. This is my first time posting on AskUbuntu, and I'm really hoping I can get some help.

Background: I had a dual boot partition of OS X Mavericks and Windows 8 on my 2012 Macbook Pro. I've been wanting to switch to Ubuntu for a while now, so I made a live CD and tested it out on the hardware. Everything worked fine testing the live CD (that's actually how I'm posting this message), so I assumed installation would work as well.

I ran the installation process, and when it finished it prompted me to restart. When I did, I got a black screen with only the message: "Missing operating system". When I restart and hold the Option key to select a boot location, all I see is a Windows option, no Ubuntu. I tried installing again with the same results.

Some searching online told me the problem I'm having may be related to the result of running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo parted -l
```

I tried that, and my results were:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA OWC Mercury EXTR (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot
 2      538MB   794MB  256MB  ext2
 3      794MB   240GB  239GB                                     lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 8493MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  8493MB  8493MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 231GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  231GB  231GB  ext4


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

Hope this helps, and thank you in advance!

---

edit: another thread shows that the result of the following command may help:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

so here are my results:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x95c21503

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1     1050623      525311+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda2   *     1050624     1550335      249856   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         1550336   468860927   233655296   da  Non-FS data

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 230.8 GB, 230766411776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 28055 cylinders, total 450715648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 8493 MB, 8493465600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1032 cylinders, total 16588800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ clear

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x95c21503

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1     1050623      525311+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda2   *     1050624     1550335      249856   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         1550336   468860927   233655296   da  Non-FS data

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 230.8 GB, 230766411776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 28055 cylinders, total 450715648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 8493 MB, 8493465600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1032 cylinders, total 16588800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Looks like grub is not being run. From within the live boot environment, try reinstalling grub, or install refind. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html

Comment: @bain - thank you for your response. In the beginning of the tutorial, I'm getting a message that the /boot/efi file does not exist. Do you have any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: /boot/efi is the EFI system partition, it should be mounted from /dev/sda1. It contains a directory called "EFI" which contains subdirectories for each installed boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread that might help
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165710

Basically, OP had to install rEFInd instead of GRUB to make it work.